# How to link two projects/modules in IntelliJ with Gradle as build system

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have two separate projects being build with Gradle and using IntelliJ as my editor.

One project is an application and the other being a library.
During development of my application, I would like to open the library as a module in the application project, and use a common compile/runtime-classpath between them.

I previously used maven on several projects and when I needed to synchronise code between an application and a library. I created a module for the library in the application project, synchronised the groupId/artifactId/version, and IntelliJ automatically picked this up and shared their classpath at compile and runtime...

How can I accomplish this with Gradle?

Comment: Have you tried the same way as with maven? Just add new module and select your library project?

Comment: yes... but nothing happens...

Comment: I can't speak on the IntelliJ portion, but for Gradle it looks you want [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). Your main application would include the build of your library. So, change to your library would be reflected in your application since they are composed.

Comment: You may try to set "external.system.substitute.library.dependencies = true"
via "Help | Edit Custom Properties" and restart.